# makefiles: how to let it know where my headers are

Tags: makefile, g++

Assume I have the following file structure in my home directory

```
.
|-- foo
|   `-- lib
|       |-- bar.cpp
|       `-- bar.h
|-- baz
|   |-- qux.cpp
|   `-- qux.h
|-- projects
|   `-- src
|       |-- makefile
`       `-- main.cpp
```

and that `main.cpp` looks something like

```
#include "bar.h"
#include "qux.h"
// does stuff
```

What should my makefile look like?

Right now, it's something like the following

```
CC = g++
DEBUG = -g -Wall
STD = -std=c++11
OPTIMIZE = -O0
FOO_LIB = $$HOME/foo/lib
BAZ_LIB = $$HOME/baz
INCLUDES = -I$(FOO_LIB) -I$(BAZ_LIB)
LFLAGS = $(DEBUG) $(STD) $(OPTIMIZE) $(INCLUDES)
CFLAGS = -c $(LFLAGS)
BIN = $$HOME/my-program

OBJ = main.o \
    bar.o \
    qux.o

all: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $(BIN)

main.o: main.cpp bar.h qux.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp bar.h qux.h

bar.o: bar.cpp bar.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) bar.cpp bar.h

qux.o: qux.cpp qux.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) qux.cpp qux.h

clean:
    \rm *.o
    \rm *.gch
```

But when I try that, I get

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'bar.h', needed by 'main.o'.  Stop.
```

How do I let `make` know where my header files are?  Even when I change 
`main.o` to

```
main.o: main.cpp $(FOO_LIB)/bar.h $(BAZ_LIB)/qux.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp $(FOO_LIB)/bar.h $(BAZ_LIB)/qux.h
```

it doesn't seem to work (at least with my more complicated real makefile).
Even if it did work, it seems like there's way too much mental overhead in
terms of making sure all of my dependencies are properly prefixed.  (I took a
look at http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html, but the `sed` stuff in
there is pretty impenetrable, and I'd like to sort of understand what I'm doing
so I can document it.)

@Etan Reisner
Let's assume my `main.cpp` `#include`s *n* headers in *m* library directories.
Does that mean my `main.o` recipe looks like this

```
main.o: main.cpp \
        /path/to/foo1/bar1.h \
        ...
        /path/to/foo1/barI.h \
        ...
        /path/to/fooM/baz1.h \
        ...
        /path/to/fooM/bazJ.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp
```

If so, that looks like a lot of repetative work.  Is there a straightforward
way of simplifying that?

Comment: You don't need to list header files on compilation lines. They aren't used for compilation that way.

Comment: Where does your makefile live in that hierarchy?

Comment: That's important information.  I'll edit that in.

Comment: `make` runs your commands from the directory you run `make` from and paths inside the makefile are relative to that location also. The working directory of commands make runs are also that directory. For your `#include` lines to work you need to have given `$(CC)` the correct relative paths to the directories they live in.

Comment: Doesn't `g++` get those paths when I use the `-I` flag?

Comment: Yes, that's what the `-I` flag is for. The point was that in exactly the same way that you tell `g++` about those paths you need to include those paths for make (or tell it about them with `vpath`/`VPATH` which is more similar to `-I`).

Comment: Simplifying that repetitive work is what the `-MD` flag (and friends) to `g++` are for. Try running it and see what you get as output.

Comment: Setting `VPATH` and prefixing the `barI.cpp` files with the full path to them did the trick.  Thanks!